# cp: cannot stat `/vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt': No such file or directory

Tags: bash, unix, cygwin

I tried a command `cp /vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt .` and I get the error -

cp: cannot stat `/vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt': No such file or directory

I don't understand why this is happening. I went to cygwin home folder and created the necessary folder structure and text file. I also checked the folder structure and names. So, why is it not working ?

Comment: what does `ls /vol/examples/tutorial/` return?

Comment: ls: cannot access /vol/examples/tutorial: No such file or directory...hmm...why does that happen ?

Comment: that means that the directory does not exists... Try `ls /vol/examples/` and `ls /vol/` to see which folder is missing

Comment: ls vol and ls vol/ are ok . but ls /vol or ls /vol/ give errors. What is happening ?

Comment: then the `vol` directory is not in the root, but under the current directory. With `pwd` you can see what directory you are in. If you do  `cp vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt .` without the first `/` it should work

Comment: That command also does not work when typed inside ~/unixstuff folder. Same no such file or directory error

Comment: I go into  ~/vol/examples/tutorial and then do cat science.txt and I can see the document. Then why does CP command not work ?

Comment: The question has been answered at - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84302/cp-cannot-stat-vol-examples-tutorial-science-txt-no-such-file-or-directory Thanks for all your help.

Comment: this question came after reading the tutorial at - http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix2.html

Answer (score 1):

You said you

> went to cygwin home folder and created the necessary folder structure and text file

So the file you are trying to copy is not located in `/vol/examples/tutorial/` but in `~/vol/examples/tutorial/`. `~` is an abbrevation for your cygwin home directory, usually `/home/<username>`.

You should be able to copy the file as user000001 says: `cp ~/vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt .`

Comment: What you say is correct, but it was said in the comments to the question that the question was already answered in a thread on the unix.stackexchange more than one year ago.

Comment: Oops. I should have expanded the comments section. Sorry for that.